# How to sort decimal values in linq

Tags: c#, linq

**Data:**

```
14.20
15.50
16.70
```

**Code:**

```
 getProductWithAllFiltersResponse
    .getProductWithAllFilters
    .OrderBy(x => x.ProductCustomModel.OrderBy(y => y.PriceWithDiscount))
    .ToList();
```

I am *unable to sort* by `PriceWithDiscount`

Comment: is `pricewithdiscount` a string?

Comment: It should work. Please check your variable type.

Comment: **nested** `OrderBy(x => x.ProductCustomModel.OrderBy(y => y.PriceWithDiscount))` looks *very suspicious*. Do you mean `OrderBy(x => x.ProductCustomModel.Max(y => y.PriceWithDiscount))`  - order by *maximum* (i.e. *best*) possible discount a alike?

Comment: I don’t think you need the second order by. It should be just x.productcustommodel.pricewithdiscount. I guess Th at a navigation property.

Comment: Price with discount is decimal data type

Comment: first question is what is your type of object for `PriceWithDiscount`, second, what is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: hi all,the order by is working if we have price with discount  numeric value with out decimals.but with decimal not able sort

Comment: You could write a custom comparer for ProductCustomModel and compare the decimal values and apply sort using this comparer class. You can take control of how you would need this to sort.

Answer (score 5):

You can't sort by *cursor* (`IQueryable<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>`):

```
 .OrderBy(x => x.ProductCustomModel.OrderBy(y => y.PriceWithDiscount))
```

Imagine, that `x.ProductCustomModel.OrderBy(y => y.PriceWithDiscount)` returns `7` items for each product. How should we sort products then?
You, probably, want something like this:

```
 var result = getProductWithAllFiltersResponse
   .getProductWithAllFilters
   .OrderBy(x => x.ProductCustomModel.Min(y => y.PriceWithDiscount))
   .ToList();
```

we sort by the *best* (`Min`) price with discount

Comment: the order by is working if we have price with discount numeric value without decimals.but with the decimal not able sort

Comment: @Surakshith Reddy: Nothing wrong with numeric values, say, `decimal`: `Console.Write(string.Join(", ", new decimal[] { 123m, 45m, 5555m }.OrderBy(d => d)));` returns `45, 123, 5555`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to sort your list ascending and descending order.

Ascending order:

```
 getProductWithAllFiltersResponse
.getProductWithAllFilters
.OrderBy(y => y.PriceWithDiscount)   // Order by Asc
.ToList();
```

Descending order:

```
 getProductWithAllFiltersResponse
.getProductWithAllFilters
.OrderByDescending(y => y.PriceWithDiscount)   // Order by Desc
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Products
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public double DiscountPrice { get; set; }
}

List<Products> lstProduct = new List<Products>();
        lstProduct.Add(new Products { ProductName = "Product1", DiscountPrice = 50.52 });
        lstProduct.Add(new Products { ProductName = "Product2", DiscountPrice = 49.50 });
        lstProduct.Add(new Products { ProductName = "Product3", DiscountPrice = 52.53 });
        lstProduct.Add(new Products { ProductName = "Product4", DiscountPrice = 100.00});
        lstProduct.Add(new Products { ProductName = "Product5", DiscountPrice = 40.40 });
        foreach (var item in lstProduct.OrderBy(d => d.DiscountPrice))
        {
            item.ProductName.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var prods = lstProduct.OrderBy(d => Convert.ToDouble(d.DiscountPrice)*100);
```